# What`s the meaning of WebClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode?

Tags: java

I am trying to use HtmlUnit to analyze html page.
Here is the code

```
    String  url="http://192.168.1.1
    URL link=new URL(url); 
    WebClient wc=new WebClient();
    WebRequest request=new WebRequest(link);
    request.setCharset("UTF-8");
    request.setAdditionalHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2");

    wc.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    wc.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    wc.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true); // here is my question.
    //wc.getOptions().setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    //wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    wc.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

         HtmlPage page=null;
    page = wc.getPage(request);
    if(page==null)
    {

        return ;
    }
    String content=page.asText();
    String titleText = page.getTitleText();
    if(content==null)
    {

        return ;
    }
    System.out.println(content);
    System.out.println("title text:" + titleText);
```

If I used `wc.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);`, I can't get my page and it returns `statusCode=[500] contentType=[text/html]`
But if I don't use it, it comes up fine.

I would like to know which page throws that exception, and why it does that.

Answer (score 0):

The option `.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);` stops webClient navigation when encounter first error. I used to set it to false. Maybe there is a resource or image with broken link (that makes html status code 500).

Settint it to false, Webclient will ignore and navigate to your page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you are right. There is a image breoken.